# How to set default date in timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is a simple `timepicker` to `jQuery UI's datepicker`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    $(function() {
              $('#pickerfield').datetime({
                                userLang    : 'en',
                                americanMode: true,

                            });
        });
/* ]]> */
</script>

<input id="pickerfield" type="text" value="" />
```

Now I want to know how to add default date more than 2 days and disable all previous dates

`Update`:-  I am talking about time picker like this [Time picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/MG6Mb/

Comment: I think the OP should probably give the documentation a looking over: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#options

Comment: @Jaspreet Chahal:) I am talking about time picker like this http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: hey John why dont to try to add a property called minDate to see if that works

minDate: 2,

Or 

minDate: new Date(2012, 02, 10, 8, 30),

Comment: @John Well that plugin you linked to is built on-top-of jQuery UI's `Datepicker` widget. So you could go through the source for the `Datetime` plugin and modify the code that calls the `Datepicker` to include the code that Jaspreet Chahal demoed.

Comment: @Jasper:) ok i got it but also i want to set the default date

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass in options to the `.datetimepicker()` function (I noticed when making my demo that `datetime` didn't seem to work) for the jQuery UI Datepicker:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
        userLang     : 'en',
        americanMode : true,
        minDate      : +2,
        defaultDate  : +4
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MG6Mb/2/

Comment: :) I want to see the default date(means date today or after 2 days) also in the text box

Comment: @John You can use JavaScript's `Date` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. This will let you set a default date by setting the initial value of the input in the `document.ready` event handler: `var newDate = new Date(); $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({ ... }).val( /*Here you can use the 'newDate' variable and your knowledge of the 'Date' object from the above link to concoct the date in the proper format*/)`.